# Websphere application server 5.1 installation in RAD 8

Tags: websphere, rad, websphere-portal

I am using WebSphere application server 5.1 in RAD 7.1. Now I want to migrate to RAD 8.0 but RAD 8.0 do not provide support to WebSphere application server 5.X. Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere Application Server 5.1 is not supported for many years now and as you saw it is also not supported in any newer RAD. I'd suggest to migrate to newer server version as soon as possible.

If you need to develop for WAS 5.1, then stick with RAD 7. Eventually you can develop with newer RAD, but you will need to install applications to server manually via web console or wsadmin.

Comment: How to install websphere application server 5.1 in newer RAD??

Comment: You CAN NOT install WAS 5.1 in newer RAD.